# How to do something for each function in Lodash flow?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there any way to do something after each functions provided to Lodash function `_.flow`?

I want to log each consuming time of the functions provided to `_.flow`.

For example, for the following code,

```js
_.flow([
  funcA,
  funcB
])
```

I would like to log `funcA` and `funcB`'s consuming times like:

```js
funcA spent 1.21s.
funcB spent 0.45s.
```

Comment: why not wrap the functions in arrow functions that call them and log the execution times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Paul Rooney, I implemented it:

```js
function injectTimeLogger (logger, funcs) {
  return funcs.map((func, i) => (...params) => {
    const funcName = func.name;
    const startTime = Date.now();
    const rst = func(...params);
    const spentTime = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;
    logger.info(`func[${i + 1}/${funcs.length}][${funcName}] spent ${spentTime}s`);
    return rst;
  });
}

const logger = {
  info: console.log
}

_.flow(injectTimeLogger(logger, [
  funcA,
  funcB
]))
```

Comment: You could also change `=> param => ` to `=> (...params) =>` and `func(param);` to `func(...params);` to support multiple parameters

Comment: And (*depending on the use you want*) you might have to bind the `this` to the `func` because that is how `_.flow` works and now the this is bound to the loggerized functions and not the actual ones that do the processing.

Comment: I really liked the idea, but I would use `performance.mark()`, and `performance.measure()` APIs instead of `Date.now()`.

Comment: You should also add more info (preamble) about the solution.